# how to go back to previous layout on same activity

Tags: android

I have two xml layout on one activity, when click a button on layout A it will open Layout B but when press back button on layout B it kills the activity. What I want is that when press the back button it will go back to Layout A

Comment: Use Fragments instaed

Comment: Try visibility in the onBackPressedMethod .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't know and haven't implemented Fragments in Android, with this I would suggest you to take 2 fragments for a single activity, and you can show/hide a particular fragment as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to Override the method of OnBackPressed()
and whatever you want to do on BackPress do it there...

Comment: This layout A has a listview but when press back on layout B it display a blank layout on layout A no listview

Comment: In this scenerio you will have to Either open an activity on the OnClick of list Item or Fragment.

Comment: And Clicking BackPress on LayoutB is actually clicking the backPress of LayoutA cause you are actually just Changing the View of A hence even BackPress will not work.. BackPress will take you at the previous activity of LayoutA.